# Counting in many to many relationships just in one column of the pivot table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Many-to-many relationships

> ```
>  table names
>  table itens
>  table pivot_itens_names
> ```

table pivot_itens_names

> ```
>  id_name | id_item
>  1         1
>  2         1
>  3         8
>  4         5
> ```

I need to count how many times the **id_item '1'** is in the pivot_itens_names table

> expected outcome: **$total = 2**

This works

```
$total = DB::select('SELECT COUNT(id_item) AS total
                            FROM pivot_itens_names WHERE id_item = ?',
                            [$idItem] );
```

Intended objective: do the **count using eloquent with model**

unsuccessful attempt

```
$idItem = 1;

$data = $Name::itens();
$total = $data->where('id_item', $idItem)->count();
```

EDITED

One solution is to create a model for the pivot table. I have doubts if this solution is a good practice.

```
$total = PivotItemName::where('id_item', $idItem)->count();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this method to the `Name` model:

```
    public function items()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Item', 'pivot_items_names')->withPivot('id_item');
    }
```

and then use `count` method to get count of them

Comment: Thanks Ehsan. My model has withPivot(['id_item', 'active']). How is the count done by id_item?